# Is it require to use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream while implementing Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization

I have noticed in my web based project, we are implementing Serialization in every DTO class and not using `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` anywhere in project, while in every serialization tutorial they are using `ObjectOutput/InputStream.` Does serialization happen even without it? (i.e. stream conversion and sending it over network without using `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream`)?

Comment: *What* Serialization? And what is this stuff about a 'temp file'? What happens if one of your DTOs doesn't implement Serializable?

Answer (score 0):

> Does serialization happen even without it? (i.e. stream conversion and sending it over network without using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream)?

First of all, Serialization doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a network (or a temp file as per your original question).

Secondly, Java Object Serialisation *by definition* involves `java.io.Serializable` and `java.io.ObjectOutputStream`.

Thirdly, there are other things beside your own code executing in any application. The JRE classes, for a start. It is open to any of those to use Serialization. For example, and please note that this is a list of *examples,* without the slightest pretension to being exhaustive:

- RMI
- Serialization of sessions by web containers
- EJB, which is built on RMI
- Object messages in JMS
- ...